# MySQL/Java database

Tags: java, mysql

alright so, ive moved on from using XAMPP and im now hosting my hiscores via a webhost, how do i edit this line so that it works with it, when i run the server, its throwing an error.

```
public static void createConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://fdb4.awardspace.com/", "1191306_hiscores", "passremoved");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
                    Misc.println("Connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Misc.println("Connection Problem");
        }]
```

used to be localhost/hiscores obviously that won't work anymore.

Comment: If it throws an error, it's always useful to see *what* (and where) is the exact exception being thrown. There are a zillion things that could be wrong -- add something like `e.printStackTrace()` and paste the output here.

Comment: can you provide exception trace??

Comment: Observations: 1) Why are you creating statement if you want to check whether connection is established or not? You can check that like this: if(con !=null){System.out.println("Connection established"); }    2) Why there is no "finally" clause in try/catch block where you will close your connection?

Answer (score 0):

Without a stacktrace it's hard, but I noticed that you are missing the database name from your url, it should be something like:

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://fdb4.awardspace.com/hiscores", "1191306_hiscores", "passremoved");
```

Note the `jdbc:mysql://fdb4.awardspace.com/hiscores` vs. `jdbc:mysql://fdb4.awardspace.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Awardspace don't allow remote connection to mysql databases on free accounts.

You can use http://www.freesqldatabase.com/

But very limited and only 5mb. It is the only free service i have found that offers remote connection to a mysql db.